# For..in is only returning the first item - React js

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I'm looping through an object to return values. The code works fine when I console.log the result but doesn't work when I try to render it as text. For some reason it only returns the first value. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
  testFunc = () => {

let spaceship = {
    crew: {
    captain: {
        name: 'Lily',
        degree: 'Computer Engineering',
        cheerTeam() { console.log('You got this!') }
        },
    'chief officer': {
        name: 'Dan',
        degree: 'Aerospace Engineering',
        agree() { console.log('I agree, captain!') }
        },
    medic: {
        name: 'Clementine',
        degree: 'Physics',
        announce() { console.log(`Jets on!`) } },
    translator: {
        name: 'Shauna',
        degree: 'Conservation Science',
        powerFuel() { console.log('The tank is full!') }
        }
    }
};

for(let crewMember in spaceship.crew){
   return spaceship.crew[crewMember].name
}

 }


render(){
  return(
    <div>
     {this.testFunc()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

New code, that doesn't render

```
  testFunc = () => {

let spaceship = {
    crew: {
    captain: {
        name: 'Lily',
        degree: 'Computer Engineering',
        cheerTeam() { console.log('You got this!') }
        },
    'chief officer': {
        name: 'Dan',
        degree: 'Aerospace Engineering',
        agree() { console.log('I agree, captain!') }
        },
    medic: {
        name: 'Clementine',
        degree: 'Physics',
        announce() { console.log(`Jets on!`) } },
    translator: {
        name: 'Shauna',
        degree: 'Conservation Science',
        powerFuel() { console.log('The tank is full!') }
        }
    }
};

return Object.entries(spaceship.crew).map(member =>  member.name)
```

}

render(){
    return(
      
         {this.testFunc()}
      
    )
  }

Comment: as soon as the first return statement in that loop is hit the function ends

Comment: ^ what pmkro said. `for..in` isn't like `.map()` where you return something in the function argument, it's more like a conventional for loop. If you return in the loop, it'll trigger the parent function's return and end.

Comment: I tried using .map but nothing rendered (see the edit on my question). Do you know why?

Comment: Use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.entries()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in the first iteration of your `for` loop, the function returns and ends up. The possible solution for this is:

```
testFunc = () => {

   let spaceship = {
      crew: {
         captain: {
            name: 'Lily',
            degree: 'Computer Engineering',
            cheerTeam() { console.log('You got this!') }
         },
         'chief officer': {
            name: 'Dan',
            degree: 'Aerospace Engineering',
            agree() { console.log('I agree, captain!') }
         },
         medic: {
            name: 'Clementine',
            degree: 'Physics',
            announce() { console.log(`Jets on!`) } },
            translator: {
               name: 'Shauna',
               degree: 'Conservation Science',
               powerFuel() { console.log('The tank is full!') }
            }
         }
   };
   var names = []
   for(var key in spaceship.crew){
       names.push(spaceship.crew[key].name)
   }

   return names // Return an array with the names
}
```

And then, in the rendering, you should do:

```
render(){
   return(
      <div>
         {this.testFunc().map(name => <p> name </p>)}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeBleasdale, you're welcome! If you want to, please mark my answer as the solution :)